# How to get $_GET to use the value you want?

Tags: php, html, forms, get

just working on an extra work project for school and have hit a wall.

I am trying to calculate tax based on province in a simple order form using $_GET.

It seems like it always uses the value right after 'province' although I'm trying to tell it to use to corresponding tax rate $taxrate.

php file

[image: .php file]

html file

[image: .html file]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You have `$taxrate = $_GET['province'];` which will overwrite any previous value you assigned to `$taxrate`. You've also misspelled _province_ as _"proince"_ in one of your `if` expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line number 19 getting the province value. That is your problem.

Just simplt get rid of `$taxrate = $_GET['province'];` will fix your issue.

To prevent future error. I recommend you add: `$taxrate = "0.05"` on your code line number 4 as default value of your `$taxrate`.